# Given job offer when expecting interview/meeting

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process

Here is the background. About a year ago I applied with a company and had a couple interviews. My circumstances changed and I informed them I wasn't able to work for them anymore. Recently, my circumstances changed again so I emailed asking if they're still interested in me working.

Several emails were exchanged and a short phone call was made, but almost all of it was filling out forms and almost nothing about the job itself. Since it's been a year and I no longer have the job posting, I actually would like reminder of what the job entails in specific?

I was under the impression I would have another interview, but suddenly got a 'job offer' (actually it reads more like 'you start work this Monday') This job is part time and I told them I would be working another job so would have to schedule accordingly. So far they haven't given me specifics as to the work schedule.

How can I phrase the email asking for details?

> I was under the impression we would have another interview but am glad
>   to have received the offer letter. As discussed, I have other work and
>   not sure if I'm able to come into the office on Monday. May I ask what
>   times and what days works is? Also are the shifts static or change and
>   if so how often? Are the hours worked in a week the same across all weeks    or do they vary?

**Clarification:**

The document they sent me appears to be (what they consider) an official offer letter. It contains

1. the start date
2. remuneration information
3. the pay schedule
4. the fact I work part time
5. legal stuff involving termination and probation period etc.

What I need to know is details regarding the part time and the hours worked. The first sentence of the email is "welcome aboard, you start Monday. Please fill out the paper work." I find this abrupt as I was really under the impression there would be another interview and (depending on the time) I'm not available Monday.

Answer (score 5):

You really want to be cautious about starting any role, part-time or otherwise, unless you have a written, signed contract outlining the expected duties, hours, remuneration and initial duration of the contract.

Without a written contract you really are flying on blind faith that everything will be as you expect or intend.  There is nothing saying that the employer couldn't say that you'd agreed to work for three months for free.

If they've said "Start Monday" and this was a surprise, then you need to push back in a professional manner.  Something like:

> Thank you for the offer of employment with XYZ.  Before we commence, we just need to ensure that we have finalised the remaining details to ensure that we are all agreed as to the terms of the role.
>
> Could you please send a contract to me outlining the details of the offer as soon as possible so we can get everything in place prior to my commencing the role.  If you can send it through tomorrow and we agree to the terms, then we will be able to start on Monday without any delay.

### TLDR;

Push back for a contract, if you don't get it prior to the requested commencement date, then don't start work.  Verbal contracts aren't worth the paper they're written on.

Comment: It is a written contract. My problem is it is missing information about work hours, which is very important to me as I'm working another job.

Comment: @voltron123 My answer still stands. Unless the contract has _all_ terms included and you both agree to them,  you need to push back and make sure all required information is present prior to starting work. A contract covers both you and your employer, it just makes sense to have it correct up front. I've worked as a contractor for nearly 20 years, I never start a contract until all information is cleared.

Comment: Yes, the answer stands. As an employee, then as a small business owner, I can assure you that a contract covering all aspects of the job is required to protect **both** you and I, and help avoiding misunderstandings or misinterpretations. +1

Answer (score 4):

With respect, I would recommend not coming across at all snarky or smart in this communication. Unfortunately the written word can be read in so many ways depending on the mood of the reader. I feel your mail makes you come across as a little uppity and potentially difficult to work with.

If you are available, I would send them a brief thank you and say that you look forward to working together and you can discuss the details fully when you see them on Monday. Going in and talking to them face to face on Monday will get far more done than a drawn out email exchange that could potentially go south.

If on the other hand you are not available on Monday I would recommend you send the same email but add that you will be available at these two or three times on Monday to discuss both the hours and the scope of the project.

Be upbeat and exited to work together in all your correspondence. Either way best of luck. T

Answer (score 2):

Do not ask so many questions in the email as you have drafted. Just ask them politely for formal offer letter and contract.  You could say something like:

> I am excited to have the opportunity to work with you. As mentioned
>   earlier, I am currently working so I will have to get back to you on
>   if I can make it from Monday. In the meantime, could you please send
>   me the detailed offer letter and specifics of my role? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, it sounds like you have a written offer that includes many details one would expect (pay, start date, etc.) It sounds like you have a specific outstanding question for your employer:

> What I need to know is details regarding the part time and the hours worked.

And it sounds like you're asking us for help on how to get your employer to answer that question, since you said this:

> How can I phrase the email asking for details?

Given all that: I have a simple recommendation. **Pick up the phone and call.** The handful of questions in your suggested email are all fine, and sending that email would probably get you your answers, but sometimes it can be easier to have a conversation versus a series of emails - you can respond to the person's answers immediately instead of waiting for another round of emails, you'll get an idea of tone which can help you form your questions, and you can make an actual human connection instead of just being another set of words on a computer screen.

Also, I would drop the question about you being surprised at the lack of another interview. If you have questions you would have asked in an interview, ask them now! Clearly, they don't have any other questions they need answered before they can consider hiring you.